# What is the most efficient way to store a collection of temperature values into MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Hourly temperature readings are collected from several animal cages in an animal shelter every 30 minutes and dumped them into a file. A cron processes that data and inserts it into a MYSQL database. Currently all 48 temperature readings for the day are stored in one table, and I have it updating them as the data comes in or if no record exists, a new record is created storing the first temperature.

We currently have a table for Cage information and one for the cage temperature readings.
Our total number of cages is 45.
The amount of data we have is 7 years (roughly 2557 days).
The total number of records for the temperature table is: 115,065

We will be adding different locations and additional cages to the system, thus the total number of cages will be greater than 1,000. We expect the data use to grow very fast.

Is there a more efficient way of structuring the table below to optimize read speed? The data is used to generate graphs of every cage that gets displayed every morning, and 30min crons to check for inadequate ventilation inside cage.

The current temperature table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `temperature_readings` (
  `CAGE_ID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `INT_VALUE_0000` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0030` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0100` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0130` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0200` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0230` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0300` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0330` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0400` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0430` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0500` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0530` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0600` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0630` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0700` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0730` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0800` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0830` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0900` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_0930` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1000` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1030` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1100` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1130` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1200` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1230` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1300` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1330` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1400` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1430` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1500` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1530` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1600` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1630` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1700` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1730` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1800` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1830` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1900` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_1930` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2000` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2030` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2100` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2130` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2200` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2230` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2300` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_VALUE_2330` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CAGE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My thoughts were to either Normalize multiple temperature readings into a halfhour_read table such as

```
halfhour_read{
 - cage_id
 - datetime
 - temperature reading
}
```

or Hash temperature_readings by either cage_id, or a todays(date) so that it is partitioned.

As far as I understand, the first option would bump the number of records from 115,065 to 5,523,120 and would grow quickly in comparison, yielding a future space problem.

Comment: Why do you need to keep 7 years of history?

Comment: @JimGarrison, I don't know, SCIENCE?!?!?!?

Comment: Realistically 7 years is not needed, but at the very least 2 years are, thats just what we had already. The sudden growth in data capture is the reason for reconsidering the current way the main database is structured. We will be getting a minimum of 1,000 complete daily readings (48 half hour temperature intervals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, normalise your structure. Just for fun, try to write the following query with your current structure: what was the temperature peak in the last week for cage A?

Follow your instinct and use this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE readings (
    cage_id INT,
    dateofreading DATETIME,
    temperature DECIMAL(10,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (cage_id, dateofreading),
    INDEX (dateofreading, cage_id) -- suggested index, useful for time-based queries
)
```

Expected row size (data only): 4 + 8 + 4 = 16 bytes.

16 bytes x 48 readings per day x 10,000 cages x 365 days = 2.6 GB per year. Multiply by 3 or 4 to provide for indexes, if you want. Anyways, worry not about storage space.

Extracting data from this table should be virtually instant thanks to proper indexing, even if it contains billions of records. Your working set (data from the past few weeks) will probably always fit in memory anyways.

(and if your requirement was "100,000 cages with 4,800,000 daily readings", your main concern wouldn't be storage space but handling millions of insertions per second)

And to keep the working data set to a reasonable size, yes, partition your table, or just move older records to an archive table every now and then.

Comment: Just for fun, I pulled my hair out when I looked at it. I used GREATEST and it worked fine, but that was one ugly inflexible looking query. Although I might add, it was a reasonably fast query .0001

We currently do our logic in Java by adding all the data into a vector and doing calculations from there.

How could we go about handling millions of insertions per second? Right now the program does prepared batch inserts by the thousands.

Comment: Good game, I would probably have given up :) If I had to deal with millions of insertions per second, I would think sharding or clustering. I would also ask myself whether storing this data in a database is a good choice altogether, since you do not seem to use the features of the RDBMS (namely: transactions and relational structure). But don't worry for now, 10k insertions every half hour is a piece of cake, even on a low-end machine.

Comment: @RandomSeed there is a typo in the INDEX part. `dareofreading` should be `dateofreading`. I wasn't able to change it but you might I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely normalize... but you're going to need a bigger disk :-)

Actually, 5 million short rows is not really a lot of data.  MySQL could handle much more than that.  5 million `reading` rows would be on the order of 100MB.

You should also consider partitioning the data by year as historical data never changes.

Comment: Good idea on partitioning the data by year. We can most definitely get a bigger disk, but does the same (normalizing) hold true if the data input was from a hypothetical 100,000 cages with 4,800,000 daily temperature readings instead of the 7 year example?

Comment: Yes.  If you don't normalize you're dealing with large rows.  Historical data does not change, right? Narrow your partitioning interval to, say 1 week instead of a year and just keep adding disk.  I still don't see why you need to keep that much historical data.